# Creating Project Gantt in ADF from XML

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, webcenter

I need to create a ADF Project gantt chart from an XML. can anyone help me with creating the same.
The XML looks something like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the data structure used in the managed bean int he Gantt sample in the ADF Faces component demo source code - then create an equivalent structure based on your XML.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/documentation/adf-faces-rc-demo-083799.html